# UIPickerView inside UIScrollView hitTest to disable Scrollview?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uipickerview

I am currently building an application which has a resized UIPickerView on a scrollview the problem I am facing is that when you try to scroll the picker the scrollview is moving instead.

For the past few hours I have tried to fix this by disabling the scrollview when the picker is selected by creating a UIScrollView sub class which performs the following hitTest:

```
- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView* result = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if ([result.superview isKindOfClass:[UIPickerView class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"Cancel touch");
        self.canCancelContentTouches = NO;  
        self.delaysContentTouches = NO;
        self.scrollEnabled = NO;
    }
    else 
    {
        self.canCancelContentTouches = YES; 
        self.delaysContentTouches = YES; 
        self.scrollEnabled = YES;
    }
    return result;
}
```

With this above code I find that when I click and hold certain sections of the UIPickerView it cancels the touch and disables the UIScrollview OK and I can move the UIPicker to select a new value, however when I certain areas on the PickerView and do an NSLog on the reported class like below

```
NSLog(@"%@", [result.superview class]);
```

It outputs UIPickerTableViewWrapperCell to the console and the isKindOfClass[UIPickerView class] never gets entered.

I have also tried isMemberOfClass which also does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks Aaron

Comment: Not trying to sound pessimistic, but... :) This is exactly why apple recommends not having two scrollview or scrolling based views with one inside the other. I'm sure there is a way you can code this, but if you can, it may be easier to change the design rather than trying to find a solution. I know this from experience as I 'wasted' about 2 days bring to get a tableview inside a scrollview...

Comment: Yep I have also thought about this also but gone too far down the design route, I think I have figured it out see the Answer posted

Comment: Ironically, Apple now regularly use a scroll-based view inside another (as with the Calendar app) and as of iOS7, using a UIDatePicker inside a scrollview appears to be the norm. Have I missed something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have figured this out, by searching the class description to see if it contains @"UIPicker*"

```
- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UIView* result = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    NSString *viewDescription = [result.superview class].description;
    NSRange range = [viewDescription rangeOfString : @"UIPicker"];

    if (range.location != NSNotFound) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Cancel touch on ScrollView");
        self.canCancelContentTouches = NO;  
        self.delaysContentTouches = NO;
        self.scrollEnabled = NO;
    }
    else 
    {
        self.canCancelContentTouches = YES; 
        self.delaysContentTouches = YES;
        self.scrollEnabled = YES;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now when I drag the UIPicker it works perfectly and the scrollview does not move at all, unless I am clicking on that and dragging it.

Aaron